# ForceDirectories returns False

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, directory

I am using the `ForceDirectories` function like this:

```
ForceDirectories('C:/Path/To/Dir');
```

And it returns `False` and no directories at all are created. `GetLastError` returns 0. I am running the program with Administrative rights.

If I do

```
ForceDirectories('C:/Path');
ForceDirectories('C:/Path/To');
ForceDirectories('C:/Path/To/Dir');
```

Each call succeeds and the directories are created. However, this voids the usefulness of the `ForceDirectories` function. Does anyone know why it behaves this way? (I'm looking at you David)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your path delimiter to that which is correct for your platform (Win32) and all will be good:

```
  ForceDirectories('c:\Path\To\Dir');
```

To make the code portable across platforms (in preparation for some future time when this may be relevant to your Delphi code) you could:

```
  s := 'c:/Path/To/Dir';  // << example

  s := StringReplace(s, '/', PathDelim, [rfReplaceAll]);
  s := StringReplace(s, '\', PathDelim, [rfReplaceAll]);
  ForceDirectories(s);
```

This could be improved for re-use (only search/replace the symbol which is no = PathDelim) but demonstrates the principle.

Comment: Actually both / and \ are valid path delimiters for Windows.

Comment: ...but only the latter is the "normal" one.

Comment: "correct for your platform" in this case means "correct as identified by the Delphi RTL", since ForceDirectories() does not call any Windows API directly to create the path but calls CreateDir for each successive element in the total path that does not exist.  To identify the path elements it breaks the path up using "PathDelim" which when MSWINDOWS is defined by the compiler is set to '\'.  Hence, for ForceDirectories on Win32, the correct path delimiter is '\'.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently `ForceDirectories` only likes `\`'s, not `/`'s... Stupid problem solved.

Comment: Most things that deal with paths, in Windows only like backslashes.